# How can I make general method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I Want to know if this is possible. How can I get value in the same function ?

```
public function getInfo($parameter){
    return $this->_result->results()[0]->$parameter;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the question. What do you expect to happen and what does happen?

Comment: are you trying to say global function that can be used everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
public function getInfo($parameter){
     return $this->_result->results()[0]->{$parameter};
}
```

Note the { } surrounding the field name. (and the $parameter must be a property of the object)